# Center path content inside button

Tags: wpf

I have a very simple path (just a + sign) that I exported from Inkscape and I would like to use it as the content of a button but when I do, the path is off center.

[image: Offcenter Path]

```
<Button Height="24" Width="24">
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path Fill="#000000" Data="M 11 5 L 11 11 L 5 11 L 5 13 L 11 13 L 11 19 L 13 19 L 13 13 L 19 13 L 19 11 L 13 11 L 13 5 L 11 5 z"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

I've wrapped it in a `Viewbox` so I can scale it and I've tried playing with the `HorizontalAlignment`, `VerticalAlignment` and `LayoutRounding` but they don't seem to affect the positioning.

I'm guessing the path data itself is responsible for this..probably starting with the first Move To (M) but I'm not confident with editing the path manually.

Is there any way to correct this so it displays centered inside the button? I have many more buttons to build so I'd like to understand what's going on.

Here's the original SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" width="48" height="48">
<path style="text-indent:0;text-align:start;line-height:normal;text-transform:none;block-progression:tb;-inkscape-font-specification:Bitstream Vera Sans" d="M 11 5 L 11 11 L 5 11 L 5 13 L 11 13 L 11 19 L 13 19 L 13 13 L 19 13 L 19 11 L 13 11 L 13 5 L 11 5 z" color="#000" overflow="visible" enable-background="accumulate" font-family="Bitstream Vera Sans"/>
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<Button Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Margin="2"
          Data="M 11 5 L 11 11 L 5 11 L 5 13 L 11 13 L 11 19 L 13 19 L 13 13 L 19 13 L 19 11 L 13 11 L 13 5 L 11 5 z"
          Fill="#000000"
          Stretch="Fill" />
</Button>
```

No need for a `ViewBox`when you have a `Path`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to put the margins and the stretch inside the actual Path. I keep overthinking the XAML.

Comment: Can you explain why? Do all `Path` need to have `Margin` set?